# Cannot Read Property of Play Error and not sure what that means

Tags: javascript

developers of stack overflow, I hope all is well with you,

I am a High School Student working on my final project for the school year and have run into an issue.

I keep getting this issue:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined
    at Sound.play (/gamelib.js:18:16)
    at Game.main [as state] (/flappybird.js:434:12)
    at gameloop (/script.js:55:10)

[Here is the link to my project](https://repl.it/@terminator69851/Rohan-Israni-Retro-Arcade-Marking-Period-4-1)

There are two times I get the same error

1) When I Run Flappy Bird Duos: (Error Above)(*Fixed looking at Mosh Feu fix*)
    Instructions on how to load:
      Play
      Flappy Bird
      Flappy Bird Duo's
        Expected Output:
           When you press space ideally both sprites (copter and bird) would load the game would 
           function as expected
             [Link to Flappy Bird Duo's in a separate file](https://repl.it/@terminator69851/FlappyBirdProject-3)

2) When I Run Zombie Thanksgiving: (Error Above) (*Fixed thanks to Mosh Feu*)

```
Instructions on how to load:
   Play
   Zombie Thanksgiving
      Once you get through all the dialogue you would get the same error as the duo's issue
      When you press space ideally both sprites (turkey and zombie) would bounce into each other and 
      all around the screen colliding and health decreasing and the crosshair would follow the mouse 
      and when you left-click whatever sprite you were hovering over would lose health
      [Zombie Thanksgiving in a separate file][3]
```

Thank You in Advanced

Comment: Seems like `game.audios.gobble` is `undefined` so it can't play